# Jquery image width and height

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to set the height of a image to 150px if the image width is larger than the height, and if the image height is larger than the width, the width of the image changes to 150px.

This is my markup:

CSS:

```
       .posts { width:150px; height:150px; }
```

HTML:

```
        <div class="posts"><img src="image" /></div>
```

JQUERY SCRIPT:

```
        var photoW = $('.posts img').width();
        var photoH = $('.posts img').height();

        if( photoW > photoH ){
            $(".posts img").css("width", "auto").css("height", "100%");
        }

        else {
            $(".posts img").css("width", "100%").css("height", "auto");
        }
```

It doesn't work and I don't know why. I would appreciate if you could help me.

Comment: You're missing a closing quote on `div class="posts">`

Comment: First of all you have a " missing there. 

    <div class="posts"><img src="image" /></div>

Comment: My bad, I made a mistake copying the markup, sorry! But that's not why it doesn't work..

Comment: Your code appears to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/psNZ7/ - did you check the console for any errors?

Comment: @Adrift I'm doing this on a Tumblr, so maybe that's the problem...

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be that when your is executed the image might not have been loaded... so wait for the image to load

Try something like

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.posts img').load(function () {
        if (this.width) {
            if (this.height > this.width) {
                this.style.height = '100%'
            } else {
                this.style.width = '100%'
            }
        }
    }).filter(function () {
        return this.complete
    }).trigger('load')
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Jgbd4/)

Comment: still not working, but that is because of the tumblr, thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0):

here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MujtabaHaider/E6HYr/) for you, you should run code on document ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var photoW = $('.posts img').width();
        var photoH = $('.posts img').height();

        if( photoW > photoH ){
            $(".posts img").css({width: "auto",height: "100%"});
        }

        else {
            $(".posts img").css({width: "auto",height: "100%"});
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

No offense, but I am not sure what your intent is.  A typical instance requirement is to maintain a specific bounding box, say of 150px, around an image.  [Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ffTTJ/) that does just that.  Notice there is no CSS for width and height, since both are set dynamically.  This is the code:

```
var $photo, w_px, h_px;

$photo = $('.posts img');
w_px = $photo.width();
h_px = $photo.height();

if ( h_px > w_px && h_px > 150 ) {
  $photo.css({ height : 150, width : '' });
}
else if ( w_px > 150 ) {
  $photo.css({ height : '', width : 150 });
}
```

If your requirements are instead as you typed them, than [this fiddle should do the trick](http://jsfiddle.net/2M5mk/).

Comment: My intention is to have always squared images, but I don't want to set the width and height to 150px because they would look very bad. I set the overflow  of my posts hidden, so if the width of the image is larger than the height, the height will be set to 150px and the remaing part of the width will not be shown because of the hidden overflow. Same with if the height is larger than the width. The posts width changes to 150px and the remaining height will not be shown. Do you understand me?

Comment: Sure, that makes perfect sense.  Then you should be set with the second fiddle, because that does exactly what you are looking for.  The only thing that is missing is the container which hides the overflow.  A handy way to do this, btw, is to use a background image and background sizing with position of "center,center"

Comment: That fiddle still wasn't working and I don't know why, I found a good and easy solution: ".posts img { min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%; width: auto; height: auto; }". This exactly did what I wanted. Thanks for your comments anyway!

Comment: That is indeed a clever solution and it avoid all JavaScript.  Very nice.  How well does it work x-browser?

Comment: I tested it on Firefox, Chrome, IE and Safari, it works perfectly on all :)